# how to replace Windows provided Form designer on Custom Windows Form Designer

Tags: vb.net, windows-forms-designer

I'm working on 13 years old .net application. They are using Custom Windows From Designer. Everything works fine till now, But every year they need to add new business in that application which is getting more difficult due to custom windows form designer . So they wanted to remove that Custom designer and use windows provided form designer which is more convinient and easy. I just need any reference documents/links/blogs  which will help me to do this work. I already searched it but since now a days no one is using custom windows form designer that much , so not able to get proper guidance. Please do share your experince / links/information with me . Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This looks a lot like a code migration.  Typically, you'd migrate from one platform to another (e.g. Java to C#), or from one version to another (i.e. ASP classic to ASP.NET with VB.NET).

In this case, you want to migrate your code from a custom Win Form editor to Visual Studio.  Unfortunately, I don't think there's a quick solution.  The good news is that there are a wide array of "code converters" out there to help with a migration like this, and many are templatized, so you can decide how to handle edge conditions that don't line up precisely out of the box.

Here are some resources to get you started on the research:

- https://www.greatmigrations.com/
- https://visualstudiomagazine.com/Articles/2010/03/01/Unlocking-Legacy-Code.aspx

Comment: Thanks for links and Demo. I will definitely go though that demo and try.

Comment: My application is in dot net. 4.5,  Its not classic ASP or any other. so no use of Great Migrations software.